# google sheet multi select on dropdown script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this google sheet script for selecting multiple on the data validation dropdown

```js
function onEdit(e) {
    var oldValue;
    var newValue;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if (activeCell.getRow() != 1 && activeCell.getRow() != 2 &&
        (ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Projects' ||
            ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Developers' ||
            ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Repositories' ||
            ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Accounts' ||
            ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Passwords' ||
            ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Servers' ||
            ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'SSH' ||
            ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Databases' ||
            ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Frameworks')
    ) {
        newValue = e.value;
        oldValue = e.oldValue;
        if (!e.value) {
            activeCell.setValue("");
        } else {
            if (!e.oldValue) {
                activeCell.setValue(newValue);
            } else {
                if (oldValue.indexOf(newValue) < 0) {
                    activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ',' + newValue);
                } else {
                    activeCell.setValue(oldValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

its working but there's a problem, it also multi selecting to all columns. Is there a way to detect if its a select dropdown then only apply the multi select to select dropdown? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you, if possible, provide a sample spreadsheet link with the above code?

Comment: Please share the sample spreadsheet, and try clarifying what the issue is. Are you receiving any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Use [getDataValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatavalidation) to check whether there is a rule applied to the cell.

You may want to make a more precise check at a deeper level.

```js
const rule = e.range.getDataValidation()
// Level 1: no rule
if (rule == null) { return; }

// Level 2: check criteria type
const criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
if (criteria != SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE) { return; }
if (criteria != SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_LIST) { return; }

// Level 3: check criteria values
const args = rule.getCriteriaValues();
if (...) { return; }
```